# Can't Install kobuki package on the Raspberry Pi 2 model B

Tags: raspberrypi, kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've installed ros on the Raspberry Pi 2 model B following [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi).Then, I'm installing kobuki following [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/kobuki/Tutorials/Installation) .But I can't install kobuki package.

I execute command "`$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-kobuki ros-indigo-kobuki-core`". Then I get a following error message.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-kobuki ros-indigo-kobuki-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-kobuki : Depends: ros-indigo-kobuki-auto-docking but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: ros-indigo-kobuki-bumper2pc but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: ros-indigo-kobuki-capabilities but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: ros-indigo-kobuki-controller-tutorial but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: ros-indigo-kobuki-description but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: ros-indigo-kobuki-keyop but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: ros-indigo-kobuki-node but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: ros-indigo-kobuki-random-walker but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: ros-indigo-kobuki-rapps but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: ros-indigo-kobuki-safety-controller but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: ros-indigo-kobuki-testsuite but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have no idea how I can solve the error. Can you please give me information on that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249942/can%27t-install-kobuki-package-on-the-raspberry-pi-2-model-b/) by [NKCT](https://answers.ros.org/users/28432/nkct/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will need to compile the Kobkui source from scratch. There isn't a precompiled binary

Mark

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2017-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NKCT](https://answers.ros.org/users/28432/nkct/) on 2017-02-07**:
Thank you very much for your advise.I succeeded in installing kobuki package!

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2017-02-07**:
@NKCT - cool. Please let me know if you get the auto docking working. For me is mobile node is crashing (Can you make the answer as right :) )

**Comment by [NKCT](https://answers.ros.org/users/28432/nkct/) on 2017-02-08**:
Sorry. I don't have docking station. So I can't try auto docking working and I have no idea that help you.

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2017-02-10**:
No worries

**Comment by [H.Ruthrash](https://answers.ros.org/users/27005/h.ruthrash/) on 2017-05-25**:
Hey, @NKCT
I'm also trying to install kobuki packages on Rpi can you elaborate how you succeeded in doing the same?